# Moving a file into a folder with Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm fairly new to learning applescript, and I'm trying to set up something for my school's announcement system in order to make it more automated. This is supposed to take the current date, check if a folder for the month exists, and if it doesn't- create one. Then it should move the announcement file into that folder.

For some reason, this worked fine until a folder was added to the desktop containing all the other folders (I don't know why, but this is quite normal for my school). Anyway, I had to edit the file path and now its not working properly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
property parentFolder : ((path to desktop folder) & "DESKTOP_NEWS")

on run argv

    set myFile to item 1 of argv
    set myMonth to month of (current date)

    set currentMonthFolder to myMonth & space & "Announcements" as text


    tell application "Finder"
        if not (exists folder currentMonthFolder of parentFolder) is true then
            make new folder at parentFolder with properties {name:currentMonthFolder}
        end if

        move myFile to folder currentMonthFolder of parentFolder

    end tell
end run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this ( except the move part ) and it works as expected. Mainly the `parent_folder` was created wrongly.

```
property parentFolder : (((path to desktop folder) as text) & "DESKTOP_NEWS" as alias)

on run argv

    set myFile to item 1 of argv
    set myMonth to month of (current date)

    set currentMonthFolder to (myMonth & space & "Announcements") as text

    tell application "Finder"
        if not (exists folder currentMonthFolder of parentFolder) then
            make new folder at parentFolder with properties {name:currentMonthFolder}
        end if

        move myFile to folder currentMonthFolder of parentFolder

    end tell
end run
```

Comment: First line seemed to be the problem.